# Timezone tables for MySQL

Tags: mysql, timezone

Where can I get the latest version of timezone tables for MySQL? I need them for the Windows version and all I could find was

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

But this is a stale 2011 version.
I need the actual data for mysql.time_zone, mysql.time_zone_leap_second, mysql.time_zone_name, mysql.time_zone_transition, mysql.time_zone_transition_type.

Maybe someone from Linux world could share :)

I even downloaded the zoneinfo directory, but mysql_tzinfo_to_sql gives me only a bunch of nonsence like

```
Warning: <path> is not a regular file or directory
```

But of course it is.

Comment: It seems very odd to me that this page hasn't been updated since 2011n.  The current tzdb is 2014i.  Someone has dropped the ball...

Comment: I've [reported this as a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes
[tzinfo.sql.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3DEzC8DrG97QkgwZjJISm02NkU/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-OIog-2fqHnQKqSRyNAyWcg)

Had to use a Linux VM.

Answer (score 2):

The system tables is defined in: `mysql_system_tables.sql`, `mysql_system_tables_data.sql` and `mysql_test_data_timezone.sql`

You can view the source code at:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/5.6/scripts

You can change the branch according to your MySQL version.

Comment: Actually there is, but it's only some test data https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/scripts/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue at all